# Code generation and make rule expansion

Tags: makefile, code-generation

Assume I have a make rule:

```
.PHONY:gen
gen: auto.template
        generate-sources auto.template
```

that creates a bunch of files, for example `auto1.src`, `auto2.src`, `auto3.src` and so on.

If I now have rules to build targets from `*.src` files, like this:

```
$(patsubst %.src,%.target,$(wildcard *.src)): %.target: %.src
        build $< > $@
```

How can I tell make to first execute the `gen` rule and then expand the preconditions for the second rule template? GNU extensions are welcome.

*Note*: I would like to keep it in *one* `make` invocation; A trivial solution to this would be to put the second rule in a secondary `Makefile.secondrun` and call `$(MAKE) -f Makefile.secondrun` after `gen` was processed. But I was wondering if there is a better option.

Comment: Do you have other `.src` files, not built by `gen`?

Comment: Then my answer may need some adjustment, depending on how you build those others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building off Beta's answer, here's how you can do it using *makefile remaking* in GNU make, which is not the same thing as recursive make.  Rather, it updates an included makefile using a rule in the main makefile, then *restarts* the original make instance.  This is how `*.d` dependency files are typically generated and used.

```
# Get the list of auto-generated sources.  If this file doesn't exist, or if it is older 
# than auto.template, it will get built using the rule defined below, according to the 
# standard behavior of GNU make.  If autosrcs.mk is rebuilt, GNU make will automatically 
# restart itself after autosrcs.mk is updated.

include autosrcs.mk

# Once we have the list of auto-generated sources, getting the list of targets to build 
# from them is a simple pattern substitution.

TARGETS=$(patsubst %.src,%.target,$(AUTO_SRCS))

all: $(TARGETS)

# Rule describing how to build autosrcs.mk.  This generates the sources, then computes 
# the list of autogenerated sources and writes that to autosrcs.mk in the form of a 
# make variable.  Note that we use *shell* constructs to get the list of sources, not
# make constructs like $(wildcard), which could be expanded at the wrong time relative
# to when the source files are actually created.

autosrcs.mk: auto.template
        ./generate-sources auto.template
        echo "AUTO_SRCS=`echo *.src`" > autosrcs.mk

# How to build *.target files from *.src files.

%.target: %.src
        @echo 'build $< > $@'
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. But I still have a question; Wouldn't it be enough to merely `touch autosrcs.mk` and have `AUTO_SRCS:=$(wildcard *.src)` inside `Makefile`?

Comment: @bitmask: yes, that would work as well in this case.  I prefer the approach shown in my answer because, to me, it's a little less mysterious, and it allows you to do arbitrarily complex things to define the list of auto-generated sources, if $(wildcard) is not sufficient for some reason.

Comment: The drawback of this technique is that it will run some of the recipes in order to determine the dependency graph - ideally these should be two separate phases. (In my own Makefile where I have this problem, these recipes are expensive.)

Comment: @reinierpost: not sure why you see that as a problem -- only those recipes that are related to defining the dependency graph will be run in the first pass, and those recipes will not be run again in the second since the targets the describe will then already be up-to-date.

Comment: @Eric Melski: it is not a problem here, but it is in my own 100+ rule Makefile.

Comment: 'make clean'
will cause the regeneration of the sources. How to avoid this?

Comment: @user447503: whether or not `make clean` causes a regeneration of the sources depends entirely on how you have implemented `make clean`. If you don't want it to, then just don't delete `autosrcs.mk` and the generated source files in your `clean` target.

Comment: @EricMelski What they might be referring to is the fact that, if `autosrcs.mk` hasn't been built yet (maybe you've checked out a fresh version of the project from your repo) and you run `make clean`, Make will build the `autosrcs.mk` target before running the `clean`. The end result is the same, i.e. the `clean` ultimately will delete `autosrcs.mk` and the corresponding generated source files, but first it will actually generate said source files even if they were already not there. Might there be a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't. Make determines all of the rules it will have to execute before it executes any rule.

Longer answer: maybe you can. As you say, you can use recursive Make explicitly, or surreptitiously by, say, building a file which your makefile will `include` (I'm looking at you, Jack Kelly). Or if you could somehow obtain a list of the files which `gen` will build, you could write a rule around that. Or you could take a leap of faith like this:

```
%.target: %.src
        build $< > $@

%.src: gen;
```

Comment: Okay, I think I will have to go with the recursive call. Maybe it's not that bad. But perhaps somebody will come up with a way to do it, so I'll give them a chance and keep the question open.